# what plant is this? thank you

Tags: container-gardening

[image]

hope you can respond to my question

Comment: No idea - we need a photo  taken in daylight which shows the leaves clearly, and knowing where you are in the world would help. Also whether this plant is in or outdoors, its impossible to tell from the photo.

Comment: I should also say I'm pretty sure what it might be - but foliage is very important for accurate ID

Comment: I can't fix your title because you haven't provided any real body to the question. Please edit to include your location, and anything you know or have observed about the plant (eg if the person who gave it to you said to put it in a sunny window or the like.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like yellow *Kalanchoe*. [Here](https://www.plantslive.in/product/buy-kalanchoe-yellow-plants-online-india/) is one that looks pretty similar. This plant needs a lot of light and not too much water, see [here](https://www.todayshomeowner.com/how-to-grow-flowering-kalanchoe/) for more details about how to take care of the plant.